# BASH: automate moving duplicate filenames by size or date

Tags: bash

I'm trying to automate a move of all the files from folder2 into folder1 with lots of duplicate file names.

If the file names match, I want to either delete or move/replace the files in folder 2 based on size and/or date.  Basically for the duplicate filenames, if file2 is newer or larger than file1, I want to move/replace.  Otherwise, delete file2.

If the file2 file name is unique, just move it.

I know I can do part of it with "mv -u /source/* /destination" but there doesn't seem to be a size parameter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The solution isn't that difficult. Just apply the tests in the order you need and either `copy` or `delete`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in folder_2/*; do

    [ -f "folder_1/${i##*/}" ] && \                                  # test if duplicate
    [ "$i" -nt "folder_1/${i##*/}" ] && \                            # test newer than
    [ $(stat -c%s "$i") -gt $(stat -c%s "folder_1/${i##*/}") ] && \  # test bigger than
    cp -a "$i" folder_1 || \                                         # if so copy/replace
    rm "$i"                                                          # if no delete

done
```